# django 1.7.1 importing urls

Tags: django, url, exception, import

Bugs? 
For some reason, I need to retrieve all urls defined in `MYPROJECT.urls` in my `MYAPP.models`. But if I do `from MYPROJECT import urls` or even `import MYPROJECT.urls` in `models.py`, and log into django admin, it shows `NoReverseMatch at /admin/`. I have test this with a empty new django project, still raises the exception. I'm using django version `1.7.1`

Comment: Why do u have to do this? It really seems like an anti-pattern

Comment: @Alvaro I need to set up a url based permission (who can visit which url), and make a management screen for that. I'm thinking of making a middleware to do it, or is there a way to override the `resolve()` method in `RegexURLPattern` (Specifying a url resolver in django settings)?